# redirecting current page to another page at a particular time of a day in android

Tags: android, android-intent

i am trying to redirect from one page to another at a particular time of a day. i used the below code for redirecting..

```
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent i=new Intent(v.getContext(),ShowPopUp.class);
                startActivity(i);
}
```

using the same code with calendar shows error as i am not using the onClick(View v) method
and it also shows i cannot use getContext().below is the code i am stuck with. can anyone tell me how i could solve this

```
final Calendar cld = Calendar.getInstance();

        int time = cld.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            if(time==14)
                {
                    Intent i=new Intent(v.getContext(),ShowPopUp.class);
                startActivity(i);
                }
```

Comment: well i found the solution. instead of redirecting it to other page i just wrote the code inside the if statement. Hence no need to use intent. Thank u all for ur answers

Answer (score 0):

Change the intent to

```
Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),ShowPopUp.class);
```

or if you're in an activity then

```
Intent i=new Intent(this,ShowPopUp.class);
```

Comment: what i am trying to do is the main page has to redirect to ShowPopUp if the current time in HOUR OF DAY is 14. i used the first but it asked to create a getActivity method. but when i run it, it shows "Unfortunately,Trial has stopped". getting same error message with the second one too.

Comment: does your class extend Activity?

Comment: s the class extends Activity.

Comment: solved it in a simple way. but still have lots to learn in this. still dint understand what was the mistake in my Intent line

Comment: feel free to post your code and I may be able to help you understand it!

Comment: i have come up to some extent. i need help with this database connectivity. posted my question and code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408076/how-do-i-use-database-for-my-program-in-android